# PCL: how to plot a directional line

Tags: c++, computer-vision, visualization, point-cloud-library

I have built a point cloud and of an object and have estimated the pose and would like to add a directional line to the visualization from the centre point (xyz) pointing in the direction of pose (pitch, yaw, roll).

However, I can't find any examples of this online and am very new to the pcl library.

I have seen the plotting normals example however, this is different.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PCLVisualizer](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html) has methods `addLine` and `addArrow` which use two points as input.
You can get the first point via `compute3DCentroid` of [module common](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__common.html). For the second point you can compute a point in the direction you'd like (e.g. depending on a given pose).